# csrf.py _reject: Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)

Tags: django, django-csrf

I am getting a 403 forbidden error and `WARNING csrf.py _reject: Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)` is django logs.

Here is my html, jquery-

```
function req() {
    var server_id = $( "#server option:selected" ).val();
    $.post("/sp/add_req", JSON.stringify({ cir: {{  cir  }}, server_id: server_id, csrfmiddlewaretoken: {{ csrf_token }}}), function (data) {
       console.log(data)
    });
}
```

and views.py-

```
def add_request(request):
    ....
    return JsonResponse({'success': True})
```

I have the 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' in settings. What is wrong and how to solve this?

Comment: According to example 2 here, you shouldn't have to use JSON.stringify on a JQuery post:  https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp

Comment: yeah but it doesn't work without jsonstringify- gives in JSON decode error. I am not sure why though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{% csrf_token %}` will render as `<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="xxxxxx">`.  Therefore, you could render it separately and then create the JSON object with javascript.

```
var csrfToken = $('[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
var data = {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrfToken);
```

and then send the data along on your post.  I prefer to use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Sending_a_request_with_credentials_included) to post.

Answer (score 0):

When using AJAX, you need to pass the CSRF token along with your requests. See more at the official guide: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#ajax